# Запуск нескольких приложений в одном Docker контейнере с возможностью авторестарта при падении

Tags: docker, crontab

Есть ли возможность запускать несколько независимых скриптов в одном контейнере так, чтобы в случае поломки одного из них, скрипт перезапускался? Грубо говоря условие *restart: always* на каждый скрипт в контейнере.
Почему не хочу запускать несколько контейнеров? Ресурсы ограничены, а скриптов много и все достаточно простые. При этом важна их бесперебойная работа.
Вроде можно сделать перезапуск через крон, такой вариант тоже подходит, но в идеале решение с докером.

Answer (score 1):

Добавить в скрипт цикл, который по error code основного скрипта будет либо завершаться либо перезапускаться, пока код ошибки не станет равным 0.
Пример цикла для определния error code:

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "true"
  exit 0
else
  echo "false"
  exit 1
fi
```